# Framework selection for a new project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, shiny, google-bigquery

**Problem Context**

We have a set of excel reports which are generated from an excel input provided by the user and then fed into SAS for further transformation. SAS pulls data from Teradata database and then there is a lot of manipulation that happens with the input data & data pulled from Teradata. Finally, a dataset is generated which can either be sent to the client as a report, or be used for populating Tableau dashboard. Also the database is being migrated from Teradata to Google Cloud (Big Query EDW) as the Teradata pulls from SAS used to take almost 6-7 hours

**Problem Statement**
Now we need to automate this whole process, by creating front end for the user to upload the input files and from there on the process should trigger and in the end the user should receive the excel file or Tableau dashboard as an attachment in a mail.

1. Can you suggest what technologies should be used in the front end & middle tier to make this process feasible is least possible time with google cloud platform as the backend?
2. Can an R shiny front end be a solution given that we need to communicate with a Google Cloud backend ?
3. I have got suggestion from people that Django will be a good framework to accomplish this task.  What are your views on this ?

Comment: Nice insteresting question but it is out of scope of stack overflow policy.

Comment: I need help on this. What can I do to make it in scope?

Comment: You can make your own decision. If you are in troubles on implementation, post problem here in a right question. Check stack overflow policies also how to make nice questions. For your current issue you can hire a good analyst.

Comment: I have been given this task and I just wanted some guidance on framework selection so as to make sure, so that I don't tread the wrong path and have to do rework later. Just wanted to know the best framework for executing this. I will research and learn myself. Can you help me reach out to some on who can guide me on this ?